# Video #1 Image Error: A valid URL was not provided

Tags: wordpress, vimeo-api

I am from Envira Gallery WordPress plugin support team, we are using Vimeo API to insert video and placeholder images into WP site. When we try inserting a video through URL (e.g. vimeo.com/155774137) it gives this error:

```
Video #1 Image Error: A valid URL was not provided.
```

**Screenshot here:** http://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0iiBe-gSuqaVTB2QkVqbW1sWWM/view?usp=sharing

- This issue occurs on my localhost (XAMPP) installation and few customers.
- Where as it works fine for our 2 developers installaitons and few customers.

Anyone knows where to look at to resolve this issue? It feels like its coming from Vimeo API. My knowledge for Vimeo API is very limited so need help.

Thank you so much

Comment: This error message doesn't sound like a Vimeo error message, but I could be wrong. Can you provide the exact Vimeo API call you are making, and the exact response you receive from the server?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. If I provide testing website link and WP admin credentials, will it help to debug this further? Thanks

Comment: That would be great, send it to https://vimeo.com/help/contact along with details about the problem